# EF5 Code First Migration - Creating database and migration error

Tags: c#, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I recently took a CF5 project done by another collegue, and I would like to add a new feature but I've some errors. So, I would like to create a auto creation and auto migration system for this application.

I've added this to check the database state in app.cs constructor :

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            do
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                // If DB already exists, tests his integrity
                if (db.Database.Exists() == true)
                {
                    bool isCompatible = false;
                    bool isMetadataMissing = false;

                    // Tests compatibility between DB and EF model
                    try
                    {
                        isCompatible = db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Exception has thrown because the database don't contains metadata informations
                        isCompatible = false;
                        isMetadataMissing = true;
                        m_Logger.Error("Error during checking compatibility of database : " + e.Message, e);
                    }

                    // If database is compatible, we quit de tests
                    if (isCompatible)
                    {
                        result = true;
                        isWorkRequired = false;
                        m_Logger.Debug("Database Ok");
                        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If DB isn't compatible and metadata was found on database, we proceed the migration of database
                        if (!isMetadataMissing)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                m_Logger.Debug("Migration needed on database");
                                db.Database.Initialize(true);
                            }
                            catch (Exception eMig)
                            {
                                result = false;
                                isWorkRequired = false;
                                m_Logger.Debug("Can't migrates database. "+eMig.Message);
                                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                                messageBoxViewModel = new MessageBoxViewModel(Resources.Resources.ErrorDBMetaError,
                                    MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                                messageBoxView = new MessageBoxView(messageBoxViewModel);
                                messageBoxView.ShowDialog();
                            }
                        }
                        else // Warns the user that there is a problem with the ConnexionString
                        {
                            result = false;
                            isWorkRequired = false;
                            m_Logger.Debug("Can't update database, the metadata is missing");
                            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                            messageBoxViewModel = new MessageBoxViewModel(Resources.Resources.ErrorDBMetaMissing, 
                                MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
                            messageBoxView = new MessageBoxView(messageBoxViewModel);
                            messageBoxView.ShowDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Logger.Debug("Database is Mising");
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    messageBoxViewModel = new MessageBoxViewModel(Resources.Resources.QtCreateDB, 
                        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,MessageBoxImage.Question);
                    messageBoxView = new MessageBoxView(messageBoxViewModel);
                    messageBoxView.ShowDialog();

                    if (messageBoxViewModel.Result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                        m_Logger.Debug("Creating database");
                        db.Database.Create();
                        //db.Database.Initialize(true);

                        m_Logger.Debug("Adds roles objects");
                        // Adds initial data

                        m_Logger.Debug("Database created");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isWorkRequired = false;
                    }
                }
            } while (isWorkRequired);
        }
```

After that, the database has been created but no previous migrations was applied :-s
So, if I want to do "Add-migration" the console tell me there is some migrations pending change.

So, I do "update-database" manualy, but I get this error :"Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'TrackName' in table 'dbo.Segment' is specified more than once"

Why the migrations don't been applied when I create the database ?

Can anyone help me ? I'm new with CF5 :-)
Thank you,

Comment: I guess you are using code-first. Can you add the model configuration for the Segment entity?

Comment: Look like problem from mapping configuration. You should post the image of model (if you apply model first) or mapping configuration file (if you apply code first) as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Segment.CS :**

```
  public class Segment
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid NetworkId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SourceIndex { get; set; }
    public int TargetIndex { get; set; }
    public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    public int NeighborNodeDistance { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrackNameFixed { get; set; }
    public byte[] GeometryParameters { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SourceNodeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> TargetNodeId { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public virtual Network Network { get; set; }
}
```

**SegmentMap.CS :**

```
  public class SegmentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Segment>
{
    public SegmentMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Type)
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

      this.Property(t => t.GeometryParameters)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(512);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Segment");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.NetworkId).HasColumnName("NetworkId");
        this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.SourceIndex).HasColumnName("SourceIndex");
        this.Property(t => t.TargetIndex).HasColumnName("TargetIndex");
        this.Property(t => t.IsInitialized).HasColumnName("IsInitialized");
        this.Property(t => t.NeighborNodeDistance).HasColumnName("NeighborNodeDistance");
        this.Property(t => t.GeometryParameters).HasColumnName("GeometryParameters");
        this.Property(t => t.SourceNodeId).HasColumnName("SourceNodeId");
        this.Property(t => t.TargetNodeId).HasColumnName("TargetNodeId");
        this.Property(t => t.Length).HasColumnName("Length");
        this.Property(t => t.TrackName).HasColumnName("TrackName");
        this.Property(t => t.IsTrackNameFixed).HasColumnName("IsTrackNameFixed");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Network)
            .WithMany(t => t.Segments)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.NetworkId);

    }
}
```

**Configuration.CS :**

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {

    }
}
```